# I can use {{ variables }} on one model, but not another?

Tags: django, django-templates

When I use template variables for replacing fields from my Project model, like so `{{ project.title }}` and `{{ project.featured_image }}`. It works like a charm.

But if I try to do something similar in the same HTML template for the MapData model `{{ mapdata.location }}` it doesn't get replaces with any value, it's just blank.

Why is that? I've been reading through the model and making queries section in the Django Docs. Does it require another technique because it's a `ForeignKey`? Clearly I'm missing something basic here, but I can't find out what it is on my own.

Can someone explain to me how to "access" that MapData model? And I have added a few projects via the admin with correct data in every field in this models.py.

```
>>> from projects.models import *
>>> MapData.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<MapData: MapData object>, <MapData: MapData object>]>

>>> from projects.models import *
>>> Project.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<Project: Some title 1>, <Project: Some title 2>]>
```

Where is the model:

```
from django.db import models


class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateField()
    featured_image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='projects/featured', default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class ProjectImage(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name='images')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='projects')


class MapData(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    longitude = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=10, decimal_places=8, default=False)
    latitude = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=10, decimal_places=8, default=False)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
```

Here is the testing HTML template, `project_detail.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Project {{ project.title }}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="project_featured">
        <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}/media/{{ project.featured_image }}" alt="{{ project.title }}" />
    </div>
    <div class="project_content">
        <h4>{{ project.title }}</h4>
        <p>{{ project.text|linebreaks }}</p>
        <h5>{{ project.get_typology_display }}</h5>
        <h5>Location: {{ mapdata.location }}</h5>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you're trying to get the map data for a particular project, so you need to follow the relationship

```
{% for map_data in project.mapdata_set.all %}
{{ map_data.location }}
{% endfor %}
```

The `{{ }}` variable tags refer to a variable in the current context, which `mapdata` isn't. On its own, what data would you expect it to relate to? By providing a loop over all map data related to the project, you are adding `map_data`, the iterated object, into the current scopes context

Comment: THANKS, it worked. Well this might be were I get confused. Since I'm in the project_detail.html and not the project_list.html I thought that was context enough, I guess. And therefore no need for looping.

Comment: @itchangry - It all comes down to the relationship between project and map_data. You need to tell it somehow what map_data you're actually looking for. I'd imagine by the sounds of it you're using a `DetailView` with the `context_object_name` defined as `project` which is what is adding `project` to the context data and why you're allowed to use that variable

Comment: You are spot on! I need to read up on context and relationship.